# How to sort x axis in desc order

Tags: javascript, c3.js

Is it possible to sort x-axis in desc order.  Naturally c3 is sorting the x axis asc order.  My graph is like below.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      x: 'x',
      columns: [
        ['x', 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11],
        ['data1', 180, 232, 250, 289, 424, 473, 414, 428, 590, 600]
      ],
      axes: {
        data1: 'y2'
      },
      regions: {
        'data1': [{start: 16, style: 'dashed'}]
      }
    },
    axis: {
      y: {
        show: false
      },
      y2: {
        show: true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.3.0/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="chart"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.3.0/c3.min.js"></script>
```

I want the graph x axis to be exactly as my x series like in descending order.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes I figured out how to achieve this.  Simply give negative x values so c3 will draw x-axis in descending order.  Then format the labels so that it shows positive value.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      x: 'x',
      columns: [
        ['x', -20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11],
        ['data1', 180, 232, 250, 289, 424, 473, 414, 428, 590, 600]
      ],
      axes: {
        data1: 'y2'
      },
      regions: {
        'data1': [{start: -16, style: 'dashed'}]
      }
    },
    axis: {
      y: {
        show: false
      },
      y2: {
        show: true
      },
      x: {
        tick: {
          format: function (x) {
            return -x;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.3.0/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="chart"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.3.0/c3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, that is the unique way to invert x axis default order for serial charts (bar, line, etc)